# NSManagedObject changes reflect changed on the fly

Tags: swift, core-data

I want that some labels in my view always showed actual state of NSManagedObject properties.

For example I have `firstNameLabel` in view. I fill it with data from `NSManagedObject.firstName`. How can I update data on the fly when `NSManagedObject` updated? I have bunch of such labels in view.

I've read that I need to monitor `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` and check all changes if that context, but that is only way to do that, haven't we more simple way? How I will check that change was done in NSManagedObject I want (e.g. if I've changed 1000 objects, but I need to update data only from one).

Comment: Use key-value observation, on OS X key-value bindings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
var yourObject: YourManagedObjectClass! // here your example object

override func viewDidLoad() {
    // … your other init code
    // don't forget to remove observer

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.objectContextObjectsDidChange(_:)), name: NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification, object: yourObject.managedObjectContext)
}

/// Object did changed, let's look what had changed
func objectContextObjectsDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
        let updatedObjects = userInfo[NSUpdatedObjectsKey] as? Set<NSManagedObject> where updatedObjects.count > 0 else { return }

    for object in updatedObjects {
        if let updatedObject = object as? YourManagedObjectClass where updatedObject.objectID == yourObject.objectID {
            // Data changed in our object, you can refresh your label here
            // Don't forget about threads if your object wasn't in main context

            label.text = updatedObject.text
return
        }
    }
}
```